# Why do I get errors in Datanucleus when spatial extensions are added

Tags: oracle, jdo, postgis, spatial, datanucleus

I am attempting to use Datanucleus with the datanucleus-spatial plugin.  I am using annotations for my mappings. I'm am attempting with both PostGIS and Oracle spatial.  I am going back to the tutorials from datanucleus.  What I'm experiencing doesn't make any sense.  My development environment is Netbeans 7.x (I've attempted 7.0,  7.2, and 7.3) with MAven 2.2.1.  Using the Position class in Datanucleus's tutorial found at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/guides/spatial_tutorial.html, I find that if I do not include the datanucleus-spatial plugin in my Maven dependencies, it connects to PostGIS or Oracle no problem, and commits the data, the spatial data being stored as a blob (I expected this since not spatial plugins are present).  Using PostGIS, the tutorial works just fine.

I modify the Position class by replacing the org.postgis.Point class with oracle.spatial.geometry.JGeometry and point my connection to a Oracle server. Without spatial, again the point is stored as a blob. With spatial I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

The modified class looks like the following:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Position
{
   @PrimaryKey
   private String name;

   @Persistent
   private JGeometry point;

   public Position(String name, double x, double y)
   {
       this(name, JGeometry.createPoint(new double[]{x, y}, 2, 4326));
   }

   public Position(String name, JGeometry point)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.point = point;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
       return name;
   }

   public JGeometry getPoint()
   {
       return point;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return "[name] "+ name + " [point] "+point;
   }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in the fabulous world of DataNucleus Spatial?  Why does it fail whenever spatial is added?  Do I need the JDO xml file even though I'm annotating?  Are there annotations not presented in the tutorial?  If the jdo xml file shown in the tutorial is required and the reason I'm getting these errors, where do I put it?  I'm currently 3 weeks behind on my project and am about to switch to Hibernate if this is not fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't present a stack trace, so impossible to tell other than it is DBCP causing the problem, and you could easily enough use any of the other connection pools that are supported. If some Oracle "Connection" object cannot be cast to some other JDBC connection then maybe the Oracle JDBC driver is for a different version of JDBC than what this version of DBCP is ? (and some versions of JDBC break backwards compatibility). No info in the post is provided to confirm or rule that out (the log tells you some of that). As already said, there are ample other connection pools available.

The DN Spatial Tutorial is [self-contained](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/guides/spatial_tutorial.html), and has Download and GitHub links, and that defines where a JDO XML file would go if using it. The tutorial, as provided, works

Finally, [this](http://datanucleus.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/what-does-open-source-owe-you.html) may be worth a read ...

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid `cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` error I suggest you to use **datanucleus-geospatial 3.2.7 version** that can be found on central maven repository.